# Getting InvalidInput : Amazon SP-API: DELETE /listings/2021-08-01/items/{sellerId}/{sku}

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am calling amazon SPI-API delete listing endpoint in Celigo integration data flow.
Here is my http method :
http Method : Delete
URI:

```
 https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/listings/2021-08- 
01/items/ANRRIZ***sellerAccount/{{record.SKU}}?marketplaceIds=ATVPDKIKX**marketplaceId

header : {
  "accept": "application/json",
  "x-amz-access-token": "********",
  "Host": "sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com",
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
  "Content-Length": 298,
  "X-Amz-Date": "20221017T165222Z",
  "Authorization": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIA4QUUOLH***/20221017/us-east- 
1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz- 
access-token;x-amz-date, 
Signature=fd9a396bbca14ce1fcbf52baad46b2076cd85dea1c9ca097b6***",
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate"
}
```

And I am just receiving

```
{
  "errors": [
  {
      "code": "InvalidInput",
      "message": "Invalid Input",
      "details": ""
   }
 ]
}
```

without any details.

Did anyone ran into this?  Appreciate your guidance here. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Just incase if someone is looking for an answer - It was because, Celigo was sending request body by default and there was no control from the front end to remove the request body object. Celigo said, they will release an update to remove request body when not needed. Celigo worked with me to remove the requestbody for the delete request and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just incase if someone is looking for an answer - It was because, Celigo was sending request body by default and there was no control from the front end to remove the request body object. Celigo said, they will release an update to remove request body when not needed. Celigo worked with me to remove the requestbody for the delete request and it worked.